# How to disable MATLAB GUI elements DURING (not AFTER) processing a function

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

It's my first post here, so hello everyone!

My question is about MATLAB GUI interface. In my code, there is a function callback from a pushbutton and I would like to disable every push/slide-able element in my GUI during processing this callback. Unfortunatelly, when I set 'enable' property of these elements to 'off' at the beginning of a callback and then I set it back to 'on' at the end, property doesn't change. 
I think I know why it happens. Probably because if callback changes anything, it happens just after the function is finished and every change inside it does not affect any element outside of the function until the processing is done. That's why I don't see all these elements disabled - because at the end of the function I set everything 'on' and that's the only thing which takes place at all. 
Regarding to this - is there any option I can change 'enable' property DURING executing a function? Code is shown below:

```
function [] = mListLaunchButton_call(varargin)

    // Some global declarations
    global a phi launchBlanker
    global servoNumber servoZeroPosition servoDegreePerDegree servoDirection

    // Assigning a class
    Manual = varargin{3};

    // Enabling "Stop" button and disabling everything else

        set(Manual.listStopButton,'enable','on');
        set(Manual.listSaveButton,'enable','off');
        set(Manual.listDeleteButton,'enable','off');
        set(Manual.listClearButton,'enable','off');
        set(Manual.listLaunchButton,'enable','off');
        set(Manual.closeButton,'enable','off'); 

        for i = 1 : 5
            set(Manual.sliderDOF(i),'enable','off');
        end

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% HERE FUNCTION DOES SOME STUFF %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    // Disabling "Stop" button and enabling eveything else 

    set(Manual.listStopButton,'enable','off');
    set(Manual.listSaveButton,'enable','on');
    set(Manual.listDeleteButton,'enable','on');
    set(Manual.listClearButton,'enable','on');
    set(Manual.listLaunchButton,'enable','on');
    set(Manual.closeButton,'enable','on'); 

    for i = 1 : 5
        set(Manual.sliderDOF(i),'enable','on');
    end
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what exactly does not work sorry haha. Are the ui controls disabled correctly at the beginning of the function or they seem to be always enabled? What if you comment the part where the "function does some stuff"? Are the controls disabled and then enabled?

Comment: Thank you for your response, The problem is that GUI is not disabled after procedures at the beginning of the callback. After commenting "function does some stuff" still the same.

What I'm trying to say is that the function probably executes anything after it end executing itself. So, if I disable pushbutton in ex. and after 5 seconds I enable it again, the pushbutton is enabled, because everything has taken place INSIDE the function. Argh, I don't know how to say it... Function executes only the last change of a variable or an instance? I think that that's the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [drawnow](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) command after your initial enabling/disabling of GUI controls and before the line:

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% HERE FUNCTION DOES SOME STUFF %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

This should cause MATLAB to flush the queued GUI events and update your screen before moving onto the meat of the function.